# Is it required to use Java 6 SDK and RE to make Bukkit Plugins, or should I have updated versions?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Is it required that I use Java 6 SDK and RE to create Bukkit Plugins, or should I have an updated version? ( Java 7 or 8 ).

*I wasn't sure if the following details were up to date, especially the part on using Java 6.*

Bukkit Tutorial Link: [Setting up Your Workplace](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_Up_Your_Workspace)

Comment: depends on the plugin if the creator used any new tools provided by the update

Answer (score 1):

You aren't required to use version 6. You should install the latest version unless you have a good reason not to.

Note that if you use a later version, then *by default* servers will need the same version of Java, or later, to be able to run your plugin. (Clients don't need any particular version, since they don't run the plugin)

It is possible to change this option (and make, say, the Java 8 compiler pretend to be Java 6, and output Java 6-compatible class files) if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use java 8, because some server hostings are still using java 6 or java 7. So if you would like to be compatible with them, you should use the older java version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement on the version of Java to use, but, the server that runs the plugin will need to have the same, or a higher version of Java than you used to compile the plugin.

It probably isn't smart to develop plugins that are going to be used by a lot of people in Java 8, because a lot of servers do not yet have Java 8. I would recommend using Java 7, as it is the version of Java that most servers use. If you're developing plugins for yourself, you should definitely use Java 8, because it has more features than Java 7.

In short, you should use Java 7 to compile your plugins if you're going to make them public, because that is the version of Java that most servers use. If you're going to be developing plugins for yourself, compile it with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Both Bukkit and Minecraft are compiled for Java 6. This means your source code cannot be compiled under that level, as the dependencies of Bukkit and Minecraft are on compliance level of Java 6. However, later versions of Java are supported because Java has unlimited backwards compatibility. This means that your plugins can be compiled at any compliance level starting at Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Older version of Java should always be compatible with newer versions. Java 6 has become somewhat outdated and not as useful as it used to be so a lot of people use Java 7. For most Bukkit/Spigot developers, Java 7 is standard as most machines run 7 or 8 and will be compatible. Personally, I run Java 8 and compile against Java 7 so that people using my plugins shouldn't have problems with version errors.